# JQuery : appendTo() within Form element not working

Tags: jquery, appendto

I'm trying to create a page where the text entered by the user in three separate text-areas will be extracted and inserted into a fourth text-area which is generated when a button is clicked. At the moment I'm experimenting a simple version and for some reason cannot generate this additional text-area when the 'Generate' button is clicked. The thing that puzzles me the most is that it works fine if I comment out the <*form*> and <*/form*> elements!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <script  src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script><script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#b1").on("click", function(){
                    $("<div><textarea>come on</textarea></div>").appendTo("#why");
                });
            });
            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <form action="">
                <div id="why">
                    <textarea name="IWant">why.</textarea>
                </div>
                <div id="what">
                    <textarea name="IWant">what.</textarea>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <button id="b1" type="submit">Generate</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: Your `b1` button is a submit button, and when you click it you're submitting the form and the page reloads.

Comment: Ah I see, this had me very puzzled, I now know for the future. Many thanks for all these responses that informed me of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **event.preventDefault()** in your context. it prevents the default action otherwise your page should be redirected

```
$("#b1").on("click", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $("<div><textarea>come on</textarea></div>").appendTo("#why");
});
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/6ok4LxqL/)

Answer (score 0):

Your `submit` button will submit the form very quickly after (sucessfully) appending the element. Prevent the form from submiting using `preventDefault()`

```
$("#b1").on("click", function(e){
     $("<div><textarea>come on</textarea></div>").appendTo("#why");
     e.preventDefault()
 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pL3L2not/